# How to exclude component installation in an MSI?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, installation, windows-installer

> SCENARIO

I've downloaded this application: http://www.babelsoft.net/bin/MediaPreviewSetup-1.4.3.429.sfx.exe

The setup is an SFX-Rar that contains an MSI installer, and I would like to write an script to install the MSI silentlly.

> PROBLEM

The installer comes with 3 components

```
Shell Extension for Video
Shell Extension for Audio
Shell Extension for Image
```

Plus these two components:

```
configuration Tool
DesktopShortcut
```

[image]

But I only want to install the **shell extension for Video** together with the **configuration Tool**.

So I've checked the MSI table to see the component names with the [MSI Explorer](http://www.askvg.com/msi-explorer-free-tool-to-analyze-and-edit-windows-msi-files/) tool

[image]

But when I try to run the installer it throws an error code **2711**

```
MediaPreviewSetup-64-1.4.3.429.msi ADDLOCAL=ProductComponent64,ToolComponent
```

> QUESTION

What I'm doing wrong?

What are the right MSI parametters that I should use when to install only the desired components?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2711 is because the [ADDLOCAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367536(v=vs.85).aspx) property expects a list of feature names not component names.  You'll need to create a transform and apply it with TRANSFORMS=foo.mst  to exclude just a component from the installation.